# filtering items with jsRender?

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I can't seem to get filtering to work with jsRender (https://www.jsviews.com/#fortag@filter)

The documentation states to just pass the filter function in when rendering, and then define it. Return true to show the record, false to hide it.

I can't seem to get it to fire the filter, it just does its own thing.

```
var htmlOutput = template.render(data, {
              myFilter: myFilterFunction
});
var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
$("#placeholder").html(htmlOutput);

function myFilterFunction(item, index, items) {
   return false;
}
```

My Template:

```
<script id="personTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="row">
        <div class="" style="height:250px; overflow-y:auto;width:100%;">
            <ul class="list-group mb-3 list-fix">
                {{for tasks filter=~myFilter reverse=true tmpl="#tasksTemplate"/}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
</script>
<script id="tasksTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="mb-1">{{:title}}</h6>
            <small class="task">{{formatstatus:status}}</small>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-0 apt-event"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Due</span> {{formatdate:due_date}}</p>
        <small style="display:none;">{{>description}}</small>
    </li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlOutput = template.render(data, {
              myFilter: myFilterFunction
});
var htmlOutput = template.render(data);
```

You have a duplicate variable assignment without filter.

`var htmlOutput = template.render(data);`

Better to use `let` to catch these kind on issues. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

A demo fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/7u2j84ox/1/

Comment: i caught that error while i was testing. I still can't get it to work. Any way i can debug what is happening inside jsViews?